# stop running code when switching between view controllers in a tab bar controller

Tags: xcode, audio, view

I have a Tab Bar Controller and 2 View Controllers connected to it.
On each of them there is a code to automatically scroll through some images and play a different sound for each image.

The problem is that when I am navigating between the 2 view controllers , the sound and the visual animation doesn't stop in the viewcontroller that I am leaving.

How can I stop everything that there is in the viewcontroller that I am leaving?

```
- (void)scrollingTimer {
// access the scroll view with the tag
UIScrollView *scrMain = (UIScrollView*) [self.view viewWithTag:1];
// same way, access pagecontroll access
UIPageControl *pgCtr = (UIPageControl*) [self.view viewWithTag:12];
// get the current offset ( which page is being displayed )
CGFloat contentOffset = scrMain.contentOffset.y;
// calculate next page to display
int nextPage = (int)(contentOffset/scrMain.frame.size.height) + 1 ;
// if page is not 10, display it
if( nextPage!=10 )  {
    if (player.isPlaying == YES)
        [player stop];

    NSString *path;
    NSError *error;
    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cif%02i",nextPage+1] ofType:@"m4a"];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
    {
        player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&error];
        player.volume = 0.5f;
        [player prepareToPlay];
        [player setNumberOfLoops:0];
        [player play];
    }


    [scrMain scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, nextPage*scrMain.frame.size.height, scrMain.frame.size.width, scrMain.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
    pgCtr.currentPage=nextPage;
    // else start sliding form 1 :)


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whilst a `UITabBarController` manages the life-cycle of view-controllers it manages, you don't get any specific guarantees as to when they are created and destroyed - and I suspect it varies from release to release.

`UITabBarController` provides a delegate interface - `UITabBarControllerDelegate` - and specifically the

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
  didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController`
```

method - for this very purpose.

The easiest way to do it is to create a sub-class of `UITabBarController` that also implements the delegate.

TabBarController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TabBarController : UITabBarController<UITabBarControllerDelegate>

@end
```

TabBarController.m

```
@implementation TabBarController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     // other initialisation here
     self.delegate = self;   
}

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
 didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
     if (viewController != myViewController)
     {
          // tell it to stop doing things
     }
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

In my app I have a pause in `viewWillDisappear`.
To make it play when I return to the view I check for a pause in `viewWillAppear`.